# Do CMake namespaces actually mean anything?

Tags: cmake, namespaces, semantics

In modern CMake, it is customary to export targets within namespaces, e.g. have your `foo` project export `foo::foo` and perhaps also `foo::bar` etc.

My question is: Do these namespace actually mean anything by themselves, or are they just parts of a single name, without CMake separating the `::`-separated name components?

And if the former is true, can you say things like "all targets in a namespace" or otherwise use the namespace as such?

Comment: Have you checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524359/naming-convention-for-components-and-namespaces-in-cmake)? It seems about the same problem (namespaces in CMake).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did not see any CMake functionality (yet) that would allow handling the name components of namespaced export targets separately. But I found that CMake namespaces still have one meaning, in the sense that they influence the behavior of CMake:

### Namespaced targets are never filenames

Using target names containing `::` in a `target_link_libraries(…)` call will ensure that CMake resolves this only to so-called [IMPORTED targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) that are found via `find_package(…)`. It prevents the usual fallback mechanism to also try resolving this as a library filename on disk (like where `-lName` would look for `libName.so` on disk).

That behaviour is documented in [CMake Policy 0028](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0028.html). It is not necessarily enabled everywhere, but CMake ≥3.0.2 will warn if not.

It's also useful. I just had a confusing issue caused by CMake's fallback behavior ([see](https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp/issues/132)). As a consequence, I'll strictly use namespaced target names with `::` in `target_link_libraries(…)`.

Sadly, from [another piece of CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages), it appears that this feature of identifying IMPORTED targets is probably the one and only meaning of CMake namespaces:

> A `NAMESPACE` with double-colons is specified when exporting the targets for installation. This convention of double-colons gives CMake a hint that the name is an `IMPORTED` target when it is used by downstreams with the `target_link_libraries()` command. This way, CMake can issue a diagnostic if the package providing it has not yet been found.

### Package components are a different thing

At first glance, it seemed to me that there is one namespace per CMake package and one target name in that namespace per package component. So that after a `find_package(noms COMPONENTS fruit veg)` you'd have `noms::fruit` and `noms::veg` available for `target_link_libraries(…)`. But that is only a widespread (and useful) current practice. Technically, package components do not necessarily map to one target though ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54704725)).

Comment: Wait, but I can have a file named "foo::bar". Why can't that be a target then?

Comment: @einpoklum CMake needed a convention on how to identify IMPORTED targets. It could have been anything else, but they settled on the double colon. You're right that this means that this prevents you from specifying e.g. to link against a library with the file name `(lib)foo::bar(.so)`, because when you specify it CMake will assume you mean a (potentially non-existent) target by that name and not the library. If you have such a library you'd either have to disable CMP0028 to restore the old behavior or you'd have to rename your library.

Comment: If you have a library with `::` in its name, you could also create a symlink without `::`.